# Georgia font variants

Tags: css, fonts

I need to use Georgia Bold, and Georgia Bold Italic fonts on a website. I did not realize these are different fonts. I assumed this would work:

```
p { font-family:Georgia, serif; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold }
```

But I'm realizing that this does not work very well on Macs. The Windows rendering is the same as what the designer mocked up but the Mac rendering is different. Should I resign myself to this cross-platform hell or is there a way out?

I could do @font-face with custom fonts but really don't want to have to download 4 different fonts because it will kill page load times.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography may be a better place to ask?

Comment: @font-face won't help you. Fonts always look slightly different depending on the rendering engine. Even on Windows, fonts look different when rendered with GDI vs. DirectWrite.

Comment: Need css base normalize is work a fine Georgia. Look a example: http://codepen.io/KingRider/pen/QGeMoQ